# AttributeError: module 'PrivateSchools.views' has no attribute 'HomePage'

Tags: python, django, debugging

I am getting the error when try to run the server.

```
 File"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\InstitutionFinderWebsite\
 InstitutionFin 
 derWebsite\urls.py", line 26, in <module>path('HomePage/', 
 views.HomePage),
 AttributeError: module 'PrivateSchools.views' has no attribute 
'HomePage'
```

I had imported all the views from the three apps as below

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls.conf import path
from HomePage import views
from PublicSchools import views
from PrivateSchools import views
```

On the urls.py have tried the 2 methods below but the are not
all working.

Method one here i used views. to map the urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('HomePage/', views.HomePage),
path('PublicSchools/', views.PublicSchools),
path('PrivateSchools/', views.PrivateSchools),
]
```

This is method two in trying to solve it by trying to give the
names.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('HomePage/', views.HomePage, name='PrivateSchools'),
path('PublicSchools/', views.PublicSchools, 
name='PublicSchools'),
path('PrivateSchools/', views.PrivateSchools, 
name='PrivateSchools'),
]
```

Comment: Share your views...

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs due to numerous views import not having a unique name and therefore only the last one counts.

when you do

```
from HomePage import views
from PublicSchools import views
from PrivateSchools import views
```

and then

```
path('HomePage/', views.HomePage),
```

you are effectively doing this

```
path('HomePage/', PrivateSchools.views.HomePage),
```

because PrivateSchools was imported as the last one.

Solve your problem by naming your views differently as for example

```
from HomePage import views as home_page_views
from PublicSchools import views as public_schools_views
from PrivateSchools import views as private_schools_views
```

and then for example

```
path('HomePage/', home_page_views.HomePage),
path('PublicSchools/', public_schools_views.PublicSchools),
path('PrivateSchools/', private_schools_views.PrivateSchools),
```

Comment: This are my views from the HomePage app

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def webhomepage(request):
    return render(request,"HomePage.html")

This are my views from the PrivateSchools app

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def webprivateschoolspage(request):
    return render(request,"PrivateSchools.html")

Comment: return render(request,"PublicSchools.html")

Comment: This are my views from the PublicSchools app

    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
    def webpublicschoolspage(request):
        return render(request,"PublicSchools.html")

Comment: Have tried your way and am getting almost the same error.

AttributeError: module 'HomePage.views' has no attribute 'HomePage'